# How do I get comment form?

Tags: forms, comments

In Drupal 7, comment form can be rendered using the following code.

```
drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid));
```

How can I achieve the same in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21CommentLazyBuilders.php/function/CommentLazyBuilders%3A%3ArenderForm/8.2.x.

You create a comment entity and then get its form.

```
<?php
$values = array(
    'entity_type' => $commented_entity_type_id,
    'entity_id' => $commented_entity_id,
    'field_name' => $field_name,
    'comment_type' => $comment_type_id,
    'pid' => NULL,
  );
$comment = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->create($values);
$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($comment);
```